# HTTP ERROR: 404 solr not running

Tags: java, solr, jetty, http-status-code-404

Yesterday if was opening http://my-ip:3000/solr then the home page is opening of Solr. 
But today I restarted VM after that is showing me like that.

```
HTTP ERROR: 404

Problem accessing /solr. Reason:

     Not Found
Powered by Jetty://
```

If I run this URL http://my-ip:3000 then it shows me

```
Error 404 - Not Found.

No context on this server matched or handled this request.
Contexts known to this server are:
 Powered by Jetty:// Java Web Server
```

I checked Jetty and it is running fine.

Now I'm confused whats not running. I'm new to Solr. Please help me?

Comment: This seems to happen if the "wrong" Java version is used to start Solr. I requested https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-10650 to improve that solr no longer makes a secret out of this.

Answer (score 1):

Solr page is now opening on this URL http://my-ip:3000/solr

And showing me 4.4

I killed java process then it starts working

Answer (score 0):

You may need going to the Solr directory: `cd solr-6.2.0/` and launching it: `bin/solr start` The Solr admin UI will run on the port 8983 by default: `http://localhost:8983/solr/`. However, the support for deploying Solr 5.0 and newer on Jetty is [unsuported](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Running+Solr+on+Jetty), so you might consider another solution, without Jetty.

Comment: I'm using Solr 4.4.

Comment: I'm using Solr 4.4 and after running the command bin/solr start it shows me

Comment: -bash: bin/solr: No such file or directory

Comment: Then `cd solr-4.4.0/` or what your version is

Comment: `bin/solr` was added in a much later version than 4.4.0 - 5.something IIRC.